# Nativescript - Problems publishing app to App Store

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to use the following command to publish to the App Store (for development - test-flight).

`tns publish ios <apple-id> <password> <provision-id> <code-sign-identity>`

It's failing with various errors varying depending on different entries I've tried out.

'provision-id' ties a development certificate + my_device + app_id. I've verified that the provision is there in Xcode. Are spaces allowed in the name - because I enclosed the name on the CLI in quotes.

'code-sign-identity' - What should this be? The documentation is kinda vague about the build automatically detecting the code. Should it be the name of my development certificate. should it be "iPhone Development" (is that special phrase the Xcode understands).

With

`tns publish iOS '<profile-name' 'iPhone Development'`

I get

No certificate matching 'iPhone Development' for team 'XXXXXXXXXX':  Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use `tns publish ios` and the CLI takes me through the required steps. Did you try that as well?

Comment: Yes I found that to work - but it works because it's using a auto-generated provision profile. I'd like to override it - it seems it can be done but one has to edit the file in platforms/ios/xcconfig file and disable auto-signing.